# what is the correct way to centre align a series of wrapping images?

Tags: html, css, image

Sorry about the poor title, but I can't figure out how to word it clearer. I have a series of images in a div:

```
 <div class='container'>
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
 </div>
```

I'm trying to make the images float up beside each other and wrap if they don't fit. Normally I would achieve this with a float, but... I want them to be aligned "centre". So if the container is wider then the 3 images, they will appear centered in the div on the same line, but if the container is narrower, the last element will warp and center below the other two, etc. After a lot of frustration with lists, floats and margins, I found the above structure with this css worked.

```
 .container{
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? Every part of my CSS brain is telling me this is as bad as using a table to lay out a sidebar.. but is it?

Thanks SO!

Comment: I don't see any wrong using `text-align: center;`. Just go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to handle this?

Based on the markup provided, yes, that's the correct way to centre a group of inline elements.

The [`text-align` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align0) *describes how inline contents of a block are aligned*. It isn't supposed to influence only text and was poorly named when CSS 1 was written.

Comment: Great.. like I had said, over an hour of frustration with LI's and floats to discover it worked with this simple markup and a single css declaration was surprising - but if that was how it was intended? I'm happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would go for your solution, I can't see anything wrong with it.